# Wordpress - delete_user_meta from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Its been a while since I've worked with PHP, but this might be a wordpress issue.

I'm trying to create a list that can have entries added and deleted. Adding isn't a problem. Deleting is.  I can't seem to identify what needs to go into the "$meta_value" for the wordpress function delete_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );

The add_to_watchlist() function is edited from an online tutorial somewhere.

```
function add_to_watchlist() {

    $watchlist_post_id = $_POST['post_id']; 
    $echo = array();       
    if(get_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'video_watchlist', true ) !== null ) {
        $value = get_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'video_watchlist', true );
    }

    if( $value ) {
        $echo = $value;
        array_push( $echo, $watchlist_post_id );
    }
    else {
        $echo = array( $watchlist_post_id );
    }

    update_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'video_watchlist', $echo );

}

function remove_from_watchlist() {
    $watchlist_post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    // $echo = array( $watchlist_post_id );

    $delete-me = delete_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'video_watchlist', ???? );
// $delete-all = delete_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'video_watchlist' );

  }
```

var_dump of get_user_meta($user_id, "video_watchlist", true) comes out to:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "192613" [1]=> string(6) "191388" }
```

$delete-all has no problem wiping everything in the list.

delete_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'video_watchlist', $watchlist_post_id ) does not work.

delete_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'video_watchlist', $echo ) will work if there is only one item in the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.